# How to read JSON parent tags in Android

Tags: android, json, arrays

I need your help with following matter. I want to read the parent tags of a **JSON** file. Below is my **JSON** file content;

```
{
    "ebook":
        [
            {"id":"1","name":"book1"},
            {"id":"2","name":"book2"}
        ],
    "ebrochure":
        [
            {"id":"1","name":"brochure1"},
            {"id":"2","name":"brochure2"}       
        ],
    "emenu":
        [
            {"id":"1","name":"menu1"},
            {"id":"2","name":"menu2"}           
        ]
}
```

I just need to find out how many parents tags in the **JSON** and what are they. According to my given **JSON** file the answers should be *3* (there are 3 parent JSON tags) and "*ebooks*, *ebrochure*, *emenu*" (names of the parent tags). Is ther any JAVA class I can get my work done?

I know how to read a full **JSON** file. First we pass the **JSON** to a `JSONObject` and then pass children to a `JSONArray` by using `getJSONArray()` method.

But `getJSONArray()` method needs the name of the parent tag. According to my example it can be *ebook*, *ebrochure* or *emenu*. Assume there is a circumstance where we can't see the content of the **JSON** only access the URL. In such a situation I need to find out how many parents tags are there and what are the names of them.

That's my problem. Thanks in advance for helping me :-)

Comment: So, what methods are available on a JSONObject that might be useful? (The top-level JSONObject there has **3** key/value pairs. How can this be found out programatically?)

Comment: This doesn't make sense: _there is a circumstance where we can't see the content of the JSON only access the URL_ If you can access the URL, you can get the contents. When you get the contents, `JSONObject(URLText).length()` will tell you the number of "parent" tags: actually, they are child tags of the anonymous parent. `JSONObject.names()` and `JSONObject.optJSONArray()` may also help you.

Comment: @KenY-N yes, it is not make sense if I not mentioned **Assume** word in my question. :-) Because there is a huge story behind that *assume* word. If I tell summary; after implementing the Android app JSON could be change by adding new parent tags. According to the parent tags I'm displaying some UI elements. So I don't want to change my code every time when the JSON is going to edit with new parent tags. If I can programatically identify how many parent tags and there names, then I can load the UI according to that. I think now you has an idea why I have written the question like that. :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
 JSONObject  jobj = new JSONObject(Your Json String);
 JSONArray jarray=jobj.names();

   for(int i=0;i<jarray.length();i++){

      Log.e("parenttag",jarray.getString(i));

   }
```

by this u will get all parent tag u have in your jsonString

Comment: I don't know why someone click "not useful" tag here. But this works for me.

Comment: It is very unfortunate that the API was designed as it was... but +1 for a small working example.

Answer (score 4):

You should read the documentation for [JSONObject.names](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html#names%28%29)

Basically, `names()`(in Android) can be used to get an array of field names, and then use those as your keys. I won't do a full example here because you'll learn better if you try for yourself.

Comment: `getNames(JSONObject jo)` but where is "JSONObject" in the above string?

Comment: @TusharDhoot Android Don't seems to have included [getNames()](http://developer.android.com/reference/org/json/JSONObject.html)

Comment: @pst what will you say after Lalit Poptani's link?

Comment: @LalitPoptani Good catch. @hotveryspicy You can still use the `names()` method. The only difference is you have to parse a JSONArray rather than a String Array.

Comment: Alternatively, you can create your own `getNames()` method. See http://code.google.com/p/foursquare-api-java/issues/detail?id=10

Comment: Thanks everybody. But I have to notify something. `getNames()` method is in JAVA API but not in Android API, so we have to use `names()` method instead of `getNames()` when we are coding for Android.

Answer (score 2):

```
public static String Fechingdata(String response){
        Id1.clear();
        Id2.clear();
        Id3.clear();
        name1.clear();
        try{
            JSONArray jsonarray = new JSONArray("["+response+"]");
            JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(0);
            parseForResponse1(jsonobject.getString("ebook"),1);
            parseForResponse2(jsonobject.getString("ebrochure"),2);
            parseForResponse3(jsonobject.getString("emenu"),3);
            return response;

        }catch (Exception e) {
            return "\"" + "Access Denied" + "\"";
        }
    }

    private static void parseForResponse1(String res,int i) {
        try{

            JSONArray jsonarray1 = new JSONArray(res);
            Log.d("jsarry1",""+jsonarray1.length());
            for(int i=0;i<jsonarray1.length();i++){
               JSONObject jsonobject = jsonarray1.getJSONObject(i);
               if(i ==1){
                   Id1.add(jsonobject.getString("id"));
                    name1.add(jsonobject.getString("id"));
               }
               if(i ==2){
                   Id2.add(jsonobject.getString("id"));
                    name2.add(jsonobject.getString("id"));
               }
               if(i ==2){
                   Id3.add(jsonobject.getString("id"));
                    name3.add(jsonobject.getString("id"));
               }    
            }

        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e.toString());
        }

    }
```

This try this json parsging

Comment: He doesn't know what his keys will be...that's the problem.