# Retrieving a HashMap's key which is stored in JSONArray

Tags: java, json, hashmap

I have a HashMap as follows:

```
Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
myMap.put("apple","mac");
JSONArray listOfEntities = new JSONArray();
listOfEntities.put(myMap);
```

Question:
from listOfEntities I need to get "apple". How to do it? Thanks for your help.

Comment: see accepted answer at http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10908439/how-to-read-json-parent-tags-in-android/10908724#10908724

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you're storing key/value pair, you shouldn't use a JSONArray, which only contains indexed values, but JSONObject, which is the JSON structure to store K/V pairs

so

```
Map<String, String> myMap = new HashMap<String,String>();
myMap.put("apple","mac");
JSONObject listOfEntities = new JSONObject();

for (String key : myMap.keySet){
    listOfEntities.put(key, myMap.get(key));
}
```